# wordpress get custom page url

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a page template where I need current page URL

I have tried

```
get_site_url();
```

and

```
get_permalink();
```

but it shows nothing.

Let me know is anything missing in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current page / post url in two ways

1. `the_permalink() /* Prints current page/post url */`
2. `get_permalink() /* Returns current page/post url */`

If you are using `get_permalink()` then you need to echo the function like this:

`echo get_permalink();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get page url like this.

```
global $post;
echo get_permalink( $post->ID );
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You can get current page url by using,

```
global $post;
echo get_permalink( $post->ID );
```

Here, we have to use **global $post;** , So, from that we can get the global post data and can find the current page data.

You are using **get_site_url();** this function returns the your site url stores into the theme option i.e. site_url.